# Variable within worksheet name

Tags: vlookup

I have a `VLOOKUP` that looks like this.

```
=VLOOKUP("MISC",'[lastname^J Firstname.xlsx]Lastname, Firstname 2021'!$A$15:$M$21,2,FALSE)
```

How can I make the "2021" in the sheetname a variable?
Lastname, Firstname E6  where E6=2021 or whatever year

The reference cell can be in either workbook. Can this be done without the `INDIRECT`?